# How do I set up my mouse to double-click when clicking once?

Tags: lubuntu, mouse-wheel

There are lot of posts from annoyed people who get a double click when they do a single click. I’m the opposite.

When I was using Windows, microsoft had a mouse feature where you could assign any function to the middle scroll wheel including ‘double-click’ (when you press just once), which I found very convenient.

Now I have discovered Lubuntu 15.10 which I love, I can’t find a way to get this feature.  Is there a way please?
Jimbo